# Replace an element when the window width is less than something

Tags: jquery, header

The nav bar when i resize the browser window, the logo stays under the nav bar, so i come up with a solution is to replace the navbar when the window is lesser then 500px with an image but the jquery isn't working.

can someone please take a look? And tell me what's wrong?
Thank you!

```js
function resizeFunction() {
    if($(window).width() > 500) {   
        if(!$('.head').hasClass('greater'))
        {
   $('#menu').show();
        }
 }
    else {
        if(!$('.head').hasClass('less'))
        {
   $('#menu').hide();
   $('#navbarButton').addClass('less');
        }
    }
}
```

.head is the header, #menu is the navbar
and i want to replace it with a button the #navbarbutton.
on html the #navbarbutton style="display:none".

Comment: `$(window).width() > 500` should be `$(window).width() < 500` ?

Comment: if window > 500 it remains the same if not change is the same thing i think.

Comment: where do you call this : `function resizeFunction()`

Comment: i dont  know i'm kind of new on jquery

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q6BpH/1/ see this

Comment: so it is working in the jsfiddle?

Comment: working perfect now what more you want ?

Comment: yeah its working on jsfiddle but when i use that same function to replace the element don't work..

Comment: put that code only. I think you are showing different code then what you want to achieve. are you sure that your and fiddle code is same.

Comment: yeah it's the same i just change it for trying to achieve what i want, that is to replace the menu for a button..

Comment: @Gonzalo this can be done in CSS no need for jQuery, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: but with media queries i have to repeat all the css for all diferent kinds of resolutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not achieve this in pure CSS?

Use a media query to set the #menu to display:none when less than 500px and the #navbarbutton to display:block in the same media query.

In the CSS for the rest of the page (when over 500px) set the #navbarbutton to display:none and the #menu to display:block.

Something like this:

```
#menu {
    display:none
}

#nanvbarbutton {
    display:block;
}

@media (min-width:500px) {
    #menu {
        display:block
    }

    #nanvbarbutton {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Remember it is often easier to do the CSS for the smaller screen versions first.

Comment: this works the same with max-width:500px; and i switch the two displays? and thanks for the reminder xDD

Comment: Yes, if you were to set the media query to '@media(max-width:500px)' the code to hide the menu would go in there, and the code to show the menu outside of the media query.

Comment: If you were to use the above however (`max-width:500px`), I would suggest you put the other css code in another media query using `min-width:501px`